# Adblock Plus is blocking my social media links

Tags: html, adblock

My Facebook and Twitter images/links are not displaying when Adblock Plus is enabled in Chrome. I removed the titles for when you hover over the images, and they were no longer blocked. Is there a way I can keep the titles without Adblock Plus blocking them?

Here's what I have when they're blocked:

```
  <div class="row mar20">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="img-responsive">
        <a href="https://facebook.com/RiskyBeeGame" title="Facebook">
          <img src=WebF.png class="pull-right">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="img-responsive">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/riskybeegame" title="Twitter">
          <img src=WebT.png>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: click on AdBlock Plus icon and changes settings

Comment: My website needs to display properly for everyone that has Adblock enabled. I can't ask everyone to change their settings, I need to fix it in html.

Comment: G'day Matt, as per your previous question, I have tried it on my MBP, running OSX (ElCap) in Chrome with AdBlock running and I DO see your social media icons. Can you include the useragent string from here: http://www.whoishostingthis.com/tools/user-agent/ (just add it to the end of your question) and we can diagnose from there

Comment: Hello again, thanks for assisting with another question of mine! Sorry about the confusion, the version of my website that's live right now has the titles taken out, so that they'll show properly until I have a fix for them. I'm able to currently see them as well. Let me know if you've got any ideas for how I can put them back and not trip Adblock, or if you think it's a good idea to temporarily put titles back in and see if it changes anything for you.

Comment: I've just gone and tried several browsers chromium on ubuntu with adblock, chrome and safari both with adblock and I see your social icons. What are the settings on your macbook air for adblock? is it adblock or adblockPlus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adblockers block page elements based on the properties of the element. As you discovered, element id's, classes, titles, etc. can all be used to filter 'unwanted' page elements.

It sounds like you've already figured out how to evade the standard detection by removing the title of the link.

It's not clear why you want to keep the title tag.

If you're interested in the popup tooltip -- your best bet is to use one of hundreds of Jquery tooltip scripts.

If you need the title tags because of some other script on your page which hooks into the title attribute, you can add the title attribute dynamically onload:

```
document.getElementById('mytwitterlink').setAttribute('title','Twitter');
```

That may or may not get past the adblocker, depending on the adblocker...

Your best bet would really be to alter any scripts that look for the title attribute "Twitter" and change them to look for something else...