# Social media items not appears on page due to ad-blocker

Tags: html, adblock

I'm learning HTML, CSS and JavaScript and have made a website.

When I uploaded, however, and tried to view in my browser which has an ad-blocker (TunnelBear Blocker), the index.html didn't quite load properly. The ad-blocker said it had blocked "1 advert".

I don't have any adverts, but I do have social media links which do open in new tabs. It is these social media links which are missing from the website.

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38341769/adblock-plus-is-blocking-my-social-media-links), which has the simple solution of removing the link's title. This is not my issues. My social media links are of the form:

```
  <div class="social_media">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/my-facebook-page-123456">
      <img src="facebook.png" height="28px">
    </a>
  </div>
```

The problem could be one of two things:

(1) When I open the console to look for error messages, I see:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT     pixel.gif
```

This relates to the following line of HTML:

```
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
```

which was code generated on the PayPal website in order that I can have add to cart / view cart button. But the button still appears and works normally.

If I remove this line, my ad-blocked doesn't seem to block anything, and there is no error message in my console, but the social media icons STILL don't appear.So...

(2) This leads me to believe that the pixel.gif and/or the ad-block is not the problem? The problem is just the social media icons / links and I need to do something to stop the block.

The blocker I am using is TunnelBear Blocker. Obviously I could stop using this, but that won't help other people who are using this or other blockers.

The website can be seen [here](http://commercialwaterheating.com/). The social media icons should be showing like this, at the top and bottom:

[image]
[image]

but they don't, and consequently (I think), the "view shopping cart" button is not positioned properly either.

Any help to resolve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: your tags aren't correct on this post. this doesn't involve javascript or css at all. It is purely about html and your adblocker. you'll need to figure out what adblock rule is being applied, and then change your HTML so that it doesn't match the rule.

Comment: That's a tracking pixel.  I don't know why PayPal is inserting it, but your ad blocker is correct to block it.  I'm not certain but I don't think it relates to the social media icons (which appear correctly for me, even with my ad blocker turned on.)  But note that some ad blockers also intentionally block social media icons -- could that be the issue?